# Implementation of Singly Linked List (C++)

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I tried to implement a singly linked list myself, sorry it is not commented but I think it should be pretty self-explanatory, if not feel free to comment. I know that using namespace std; is not optimal, but I figured it would be okay for this little example. Same goes for defining the class right in the main.cpp file (and in the declaration). I have two questions:

1. Is this even a correct implementation or did I miss something important? The methods worked as expected for me.
2. Would it make any sense to use smart pointers here? If yes, why? And what would I have to change for it to work?

Thank you for your time, I would appreciate any answers! :)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
int32_t data;
Node* next;
};

class linked_list
{
public:

linked_list() : last{ NULL }, tmp{ NULL }, begin{ NULL } {};

~linked_list()
{
    clear();
}
void push_back(int32_t data)
{
    if (begin)
    {
        tmp = new Node;
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        last->next = tmp;
        last = tmp;
        tmp = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        begin = new Node;
        begin->data = data;
        begin->next = NULL;
        last = begin;
    }
}
void display_all()
{
    if (begin)
    {
        tmp = begin;
        while (tmp)
        {
            cout << tmp->data << endl;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "List is empty." << endl;
    }
}
void clear()
{
    while (tmp != last)
    {
        tmp = begin->next;
        delete begin;
        begin = tmp;
    }
    delete last;
    begin = NULL;
    tmp = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    }
private:
    Node* last;
    Node* begin;
    Node* tmp;
};
```

PS:

(Someone told me this would fit better on this site than on Stack Overflow so I am reposting.)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We only review working code here - after reading the body of your post it sounds like it does work, but your title makes it sound like you aren't sure. Can you [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/251273/edit) your question to make the title & body explicit that this works to the best of your knowledge?

Comment: `display_all`: Instead of hard-coding it as output to `cout`, allow output to an arbitrary ostream. Better yet, rewrite this to override `operator <<`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `struct Node` would benefit from its own constructor. As a side note, if you don't want to expose `struct Node` to the client (and trust me, you don't), better make it private to `class LinkedList`.
- `tmp` doesn't deserve to be a class member. It is strictly local to each method.
- **DRY**. `push_back` could and should be streamlined:

  ```
    struct Node * tmp = new Node(data);
    if (begin) {
        last->next = tmp;
    } else {
        begin = tmp;
    }
    last = tmp;
  ```
- `display_all` should not print anything on the empty list. The caller might be greatly confused.
- `clear` could and should be streamlined. Run the loop till `nullptr`:

  ```
    while (begin) {
        struct Node * tmp = begin->next;
        delete begin;
        begin = tmp;
    }
    last = nullptr;
  ```

  As a side note, prefer `nullptr` to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain further what you mean by "streamlining"?

Comment: @TomGebel See [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/streamline), especially the second meaning; the emphasis on _simpler_. A very important concept in software engineering.

Comment: Oh, haha thanks. I thought it might be a technical term, english is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Actually, making `Node` a simple `struct` simplifies implementation of `linked_list`, and is thus the way to go.

Comment: For `clear`, this is not just streamlining - in the OP version it is not clear to me why `tmp != last` upon entry when the list is not empty (though this is *possibly* true somehow)

Answer (score 6):

### General Observations

Welcome to Code Review. It is helpful when you provide the code that tested the class as well as the class so that we can do a better code review.

As noted by VNP modern C++ uses nullptr rather than NULL, this helps differentiate it from the C programming language.

Obvious additional possible methods are `addNode()`, and `deleteNode()` although the push back method does basically implement the `addNode()` method. A method to search through the linked list might also be helpful.

As VNP also noted it would be better if the class linked_list contained the class Node.

If you follow VNP's advice about `display_all()` then that method becomes much simpler because the while loop won't be entered at all if `begin` is equal to nullptr.

### Avoid `using namespace std;`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

Answer (score 6):

There's an implementation trick for linked lists which simplifies a lot of the logic. If your per-node data isn't too large that this is wasteful, consider

```
class linked_list
{
  struct Node
  {
    int32_t data;
    Node* next;
  };

  Node sentinel {0, nullptr};
  Node *last {&sentinel};

  // ...
};
```

Now: you don't need a special case for an empty list, because `last` is always non-NULL. Just replace references to `begin` with `sentinel.next`.

See how vnp's streamlined `push_back` becomes simpler still:

```
void push_back(int32_t data)
{
  struct Node *tmp = new Node{data};
  last->next = tmp;
  last = tmp;
}
```

---

Potential improvements:

- if the per-node data *is* too large, you can split the Node type into two parts:

  ```
    struct NodeLink { NodeLink *next; };
    struct Node : public NodeLink { LargeObject data; };

    NodeLink sentinel {nullptr};
    NodeLink *last {&sentinel};
  ```

  This will add some casts when you're returning data, but doesn't otherwise complicate things too much.
- if sentinel *does* contain data, and if your data type has a well-known "invalid" value, you should probably store that in `sentinel`. You should never be reading that field, so it's sensible to make it easy to detect.
- consider documenting your class invariants, even when you don't comment every individual method. These invariants often give you clear conditions you can assert on, or write unit tests for, if things aren't behaving as you expect. For example:

  1. `last` must **never** be `nullptr`
  2. `last->next` must **always** be `nullptr`
  3. `sentinel.next` must never point to `sentinel` (there are uses for circular lists, but that isn't what you've chosen to write)
  4. `sentinel.data` (assuming the original Node structure) must never be read or written
  5. there must be no cycles in the list

Comment: That can be done without storing a full Node in the linked_list class: Separate out the links, store them first, and store one set in the linked_list. Only convert from pointer to links to pointer to full Node when and if the Node must be destroyed or its data accessed.

Comment: True, although I wanted to keep it simple for the _my first linked list_ implementation. I'm always surprised at how many tutorials miss out good practice even on the simplest structures.

Comment: True enough. I wonder why nobody mentioned the rule-of-three though.

Comment: I really thought this answer was long enough covering only the core (more-or-less language agnostic) data structure. Actually coding the whole thing to what I'd consider a good standard seems ... probably worthwhile, but more effort than I have to spare.